# Is there a way to hook ReactJS onto dynamic elements from backbone?

Tags: reactjs

Is there away to make React.render() not get called until backbone view has been rendered. Because that generates the dynamic DOM element that React.render is going to hook on?

Is there any "beautiful" way to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `React.render` in the `render` method of your view, and call `React.unmountComponentAtNode` in its `remove` method.

```js
var ReactView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    React.render(<MyComponent />, this.el);
    return this;
  },
  remove: function() {
    React.unmountComponentAtNode(this.el);
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
  },
});
```

In your case, you would probably not directly render in `this.el`, but select an child element to render into via jQuery or DOM APIs.